# parameterized function is None in a list of Bounded Methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameterized

I have the following code.

```
from parameterized import parameterized

class XYZ():
    @property
    def my_funcs(self):
        return [self.A, self.B, self.C]

    def A(self):
        do something
    def B(self):
        do something
    @parameterized.expand(parameters)
    def C(self, var1_parameter, var2_parameter):
        do something with the parameters
```

Now in a different place i do:

```
for func in self.my_funcs:
    print(func.__name__)
    <call func>
```

I get A,B (bound methods) here but C is None.

How to make C as Not None ? What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: That decorator doesn't return the function it decorates; it generates new methods with different names. You aren't supposed to use it for regular code, but for generating test methods that you are typically called for you by the test runner; you don't really work *with* the code it generates.

Comment: @chepner , so how to get that parameterized function ?

Comment: Why do you think you *need* to get it?

Comment: I want to call A, B and C from a different module. A, B are bound methods , but the moment i make C as parameterized it becomes None . I want to call C and use the parameters passed to it .

Comment: Why do you need to call `C` from a different module? Again, `parameterized` is meant to generate *test* code, not write production code.